# Modify the visibility of a form field label with #label_display attribute

Tags: 7, hooks

In D7, I am trying to "hide" a field label through form_alter:

```
 case 'postal_code_node_form':

   // Set fields as not required
    $form['title']['#required'] = FALSE;
    $form['body']['#required'] =  FALSE;

    // Add css to hide fields.
    $form['body']['#attributes']  = array('style' => 'display:none');
    $form['title']['#attributes'] = array('style' => 'display:none;');

    $form['body']['#label_display']  = 'hidden';
    $form['title']['#label_display'] = 'hidden';

    break;
```

Unfortunately, the label is still displayed. I could do it through CSS or JavaScript, but I would prefer doing this through `hook_form_alter()`, so all form modifications are at the same place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is over a year old, but completely removing the form labels in this way is probably not a good idea in terms of accessibility.

Instead, take a look at [#title_display](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#title_display) defined by the FormAPI. FieldAPI has something very similar called #label_display.

Comment: Looking back, this actually is better. Thanks for sharing friend.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
unset($form['title']['#title']);
unset($form['body']['und'][0]['#title']);
```

you can use dpm($form); to find labels in the form array.

I was using CSS before and I'll go the hook_form_alter or hook_form_id_alter route as well.